# Conflicting handlers for Global commands such as copy, cut

Tags: eclipse-plugin

In my product and in one of the Navigator, we are supposed to provide the 'Copy' functionality.
When the 'copy' is invoked, some checks have to be made before copying the contents to the clipboard.
So, I added a custom handler to the Eclipse's Global command 'Copy'. When the 'copy' is invoked there is a conflict of handlers. The error I'm getting is

> Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy:
>   {org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WidgetMethodHandler@36f05595} vs
>   {MyHandler}.

The code I use for adding the Handler

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy"
            class="MyHandler">
    </handler>
</extension>
```

The code for adding the menu item is:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=group.edit">
     <command
           commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy"
           icon="copy.gif"
           id="copyResource"
           label="Copy"
           style="push">
        <visibleWhen
              checkEnabled="true">
           <iterate
                 ifEmpty="false"
                 operator="or">
              <or>
                 <instanceof
                       value="MyNavigatorClass">
                 </instanceof>
              </or>
           </iterate>
        </visibleWhen>
     </command>
  </menuContribution>
```

Please, let me know how to resolve this conflict.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: You probably need to add an `<activeWhen>` condition to your handler definition so that Eclipse knows when it should be used.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Yes you are right. I missed the activeWhen condition. As I have activeWhen condition, the custom handler also became default handler. I guess there should not be more than one default handlers for a command